# Why should I use strapi cms with React?

Tags: strapi

I want to start a project but I am unable to select a technology. I basically work in JavaScript. So, develop a project with JavaScript both in front end and back end will be good for me. But I need a suggestion regarding a headless cms called Strapi. Why should I use it with React? What is the advantage and disadvantage of using strapi with react. Because Strapi is still fixing many bugs they had with their alpha version. So, I need a suggestion for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You are not required to use React in your client application while creating a project with Strapi. The whole concept of is that Strapi is front-end agnostic which means that you can use it with your preferred framework or library.

The administration panel which is provided with your project is built with React, however it is completely different than your client application.

Answer (score 1):

You already said, [Strapi](https://strapi.io/blog/strapi-starter-react-blog) is a *Headless CMS*, which is defined as:

> A headless CMS is a back-end only content management system (CMS)
> built from the ground up as a content repository that makes content
> accessible via a RESTful API for display on any device.
> [source](https://www.storyblok.com/tp/headless-cms-explained)

This explains why it is NOT A MUST to use a React Library, @[scoupette](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57854355/4307534) pointed out. It does not work with REACT itself, it just sends you a data as a response, when you query something or gaining access to somewhere.
Strapi is meant to stay as a backend. Be responsible for all hard work like authentication, content type management and flexibility. When you create a content type in Strapi, you are not limited by creating only Posts or Pages, as it would be on a [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/) default CMS configuration.

---

When you start developing in Strapi, generally is enough to control the backend and whole system you have created only by sending and receiving some JSON data between the listening server on default `:1337` port. I do it with [Postman](https://www.postman.com/). Whenever you decide to build a frontend, you start "rendering" the JSON responses got from Strapi. They might be displayed on your web app using: React, Gatsby, Angular, Next.js and many more. You can find their "Blog" demos with those frontend frameworks on the [website](https://strapi.io/blog/building-a-static-website-using-gatsby-and-strapi).

---

Now lets have a look at the second part of the question:

> What is the advantage and disadvantage of using strapi with react

Let's reassemble the question: Pros and Cons of using React with a *Headless CMS*. To know that you have to compare it with other opportunities we have, but that might get us out of the topic. Instead you might like to refer more experienced users of the frameworks in [The Best JS Frameworks for Front End](https://rubygarage.org/blog/best-javascript-frameworks-for-front-end).